# Integral of $\int\frac{{\sqrt[4]{x}}}{{1+\sqrt{x}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to know:

$$\int\frac{{\sqrt[4]{x}}}{{1+\sqrt{x}}}dx$$

[My attempt]

Set $\sqrt[4]{x}$=t, then $dx=4t^3dt$.

And I got $4\int\frac{t^4}{1+t^2}dt$.

I know the answer but I have no idea how to transform into $4\int(t^2-1+\frac{1}{1+t^2})dt$.

I would like to know how to transform it and a better way to solve it if there is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I get $4\int\frac{t^4}{1+t^2}dt$.

Comment: Use the division

Comment: You forgot to multiply your $\;dx=4t^3 dt\;$ by $\;\sqrt[4]x=t\;$ in the numerator...

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the right integrand:

$$\frac{t^4}{t^2+1}$$

you can write it as $$\frac{t^4-1}{t^2+1}+\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$

Then use that $t^4-1=(t^2+1)(t^2-1).$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is nice and clear.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt[4]x}{1+\sqrt{x}}\, dx &=\int \frac{t(4t^3)}{1+t^2}\, dt\\
&= 4 \int\frac{t^4}{1+t^2}  \, dt\\
&= 4 \int \frac{t^4+t^2-t^2-1+1}{1+t^2} \, dt \\
&= 4 \int t^2 -1 + \frac1{1+t^2} \, dt \\
&= 4 \left(\frac{t^3}{3}-t+\tan^{-1}t \right) + C \\
&=4 \left(\frac{x^\frac34}{3}-\sqrt[4]x+\tan^{-1}\sqrt[4]x \right) + C \\
\end{align}